# Variable scope and reference in OOP

Tags: oop, variables, object, reference, scope

While coding a function in a class that is supposed to be instantiated, some variables are used only temporarily - e.g. as a counter in a `for` loop - some are globals and others are returned and/or "stored" in the object's instance as `instance.variable`, `instance->variable`... depending on the syntax.

My question is, should I always use `object.variable =` when defining a variable in said function, or should I only use it if I intend to return it or make it available for the user?

I'm no professional so I'm not sure if I'm looking at it the right way, but from where I see it there are a few reasons why I should use one or the other, as well as some advantages and disadvantages on always using `object.variable`:

`variable`

- If the scope should be only the function where it is defined, OR
- If it's a global (and obviously not unique to each instance).

`object.variable`:

- If it should be accessible for another method or for the user.
- If it should be unique to each instance.

And

- It's always accessible within the scope you set it, eliminating possible scope issues.
- It may have security implications.

---

Am I looking at this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the term 'variable' to designate three distinct notions:

- A variable declared in a function is a *local variable*;
- A variable declared in a class is a *member attribute*, or an
  *instance variable*;
- A variable declared in a class (and static) is a *class variable*.

A **local variable** is accessible **only** from the block in which it is declared, be it a condition, a loop or a function. Your loop counter variable should be **local**, because you won't use it elsewhere. Plus, it can't be an attribute because it has nothing to do with your instance.

Use: `variable`

A **member attribute** is a property bound to the instance. It characterizes it. Thus it is not available (and doesn't exist in memory) until you instantiate the object. It is declared inside the class, but outside of any method.  You also have to precise it's visibility (public, protected, private). See [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Never mark a member public unless you have a good reason to.

A public member (be it a property or a method) can be accessed this way outside of a class:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.myMethod();
```

When you want to use it inside your class, from one of your method, for instance, you can use `variable`. However, using `this.variable` is a good practice: It is possible to declare a local variable with the same name as an attribute. It could become a real nightmare if you don't stick to this habit. Note that the `this` keyword may differ depending on which language you work with.

A **class variable/method** exists independently of any instances created. It exists before you ever make a new instance. There will be only one copy, regardless of how many instances of the class exist. Just as instance member, you have to set a visibility.
It is a good practice to use `MyClass.member`, be it inside or outside the class.

I hope that answers your question.